# SPSS Python Error

Tags: python, spss

Getting the following error when trying to run SPSS from an external Python IDE.

```
import spss
```

yields the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\USER\workspace\SPSS\src\NE ASQ 2010.py", line 6, in <module>
    import spss
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\spss180\spss\spss.py", line 16, in <module>
    error = errCode()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\spss180\spss\errMsg.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.errMsg = errTable['okay'][str(0)]
KeyError: 'okay'
```

Ran the Python essentials plug-in with no errors.  Funny thing is that I dont get an error when I run this in a syntax

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
num = spss.GetVariableCount()
print num
END PROGRAM.
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Brock

Comment: It looks like it's choking while trying to give you an error. What's near line 16 in spss.py?

Comment: Somewhat new to Python....can't follow the error.  Line 16 is just the second file statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out the issue. I needed to configure Eclipse to see the external python modules that are created when you install the SPSS/Python plugin.  I had to set a reference to the modules when configuring the project.

Once I did that, it looks like I am up and running!